# Windows 7 setup doesn't see hard drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, windows-installation

I have a blank hard drive which I am trying to install Windows 7 on.

The BIOS can see the drive is connected but when I go through the Windows setup it doesn't detect the drive.

If I load my other hard drive with Windows 7 on it, My Computer can see the drive (as the BIOS did), but if I start the install through Windows, the setup still cannot see the disk.

Some information that may help:

- I'm trying to install Windows 7 Professional 32-bit
- The disk is a 500GB WD SATA
- The motherboard is an MSI K9A2 CF-F

Comment: How does the install program inform you that "it doesn't detect the drive"? Is the disk partitioning menu screen empty, or does the install program abort with a "no drives were found", or ???

Answer (score 1):

More than likely, Win 7 doesnt recognize the SATA hard disk controller.  You need to press <kbd>F6</kbd> after the installer fails to load additional drivers.  The drivers should with the motherboard drivers from the MSI website.  Copy them to a USB stick to make your life easier.  Once the drivers are loaded, the install should see the drive.

Comment: "F6" has been deprecated.  The Win7 installer has a menu option to load drivers (from the select drive/partition screen) that will let you browse media to find the drivers.

Comment: I will try this when I get home, but if Win7 doesn't recognize my disk, howcome I can see the disk in My Computer when running other Win7 instance created from the same disk?